# Signed java app (.jar) is regarded as untrusted in firefox

Tags: java, certificate, jarsigner

I signed my .jar with a certificate chain without having errors (result: jar signed).
Using the verify however results in

```
"jarsigner: java.lang.SecurityException: cannot verify signature block file META-INF/SCHMITZ"
```

The command for signing I used is as follows:-

```
jarsigner -keystore "%$keystore%" -verbose -certs -certchain 
"%$certchainfile_own%" -tsa http://zeitstempel.dfn.de/ -storepass %pw% 
 %$jar% schmitz
```

In firefox the .jar is regarded as untrusted `(unsigned?)`.

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Are you using the latest firefox?

Comment: Thank you for answering! All your suggestions are good. However, all the issues were ok. After playing around a bit more I found my problem: I signed the jar-file before with invalid signatures and did not delete them in the META-INF section.

Answer (score 0):

Here some points you should check:

- Did you generate your certificate by yourself?
- Maybe it is generated by a trust center FireFox does not know.
- Do you use a code signing certificate? There are differences between e.g. certificates for website ssl or codesigning.